# How to total the output

Tags: c++

I can't output the total number of sales, desired output must like this:

Salesman 1 sales: 20000 Sales 15%

Salesman 2 sales: 15000 Sales 15%

Salesman 3 sales: 10000 Sales 13%

Salesman 4 sales: 5000 Sales 13%

Salesman 5 sales: 12000 Sales 13%

Salesman 6 sales: 25000 Sales 20%

Total Sales:

20% - 1

15% - 2

13% - 3

Here's my code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
for (int x = 1; x <= salesMan; x++)
        {
            if (sales[x] > 20000)
            {
                a = x + a;

                cout << "Salesman " << x << " Sales: " << sales[x] << "  20%";
                cout << "\n";
            }
            else if (sales[x] <= 20000 && sales[x] >= 15000)
            {
                b = x + b;

                cout << "Salesman " << x << " Sales: " << sales[x] << "  15%";
                cout << "\n";
            }
            else if (sales[x] < 15000 && sales[x] >= 0)
            {
                c = x + c;
                cout << "Salesman " << x << " Sales: " << sales[x] << "  13%";
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }

    cout <<"20% - "<< a <<"\n";
    cout <<"15% - "<< b <<"\n";
    cout <<"13% - "<< c <<"\n";
```

Solve:
`a += 1` not `a = x + a` <--- this code adds the index of the salesman so that's why i cant get my answer.

Thanks @TZHX

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: `Total Sales:

20% - 6

15% - 3

13% - 12`

Comment: Do you maybe want `a += 1` etc rather than adding the value of the index you're currently on?

Comment: yes i get my error it it adds the array of the salesman rather than just adding 1 into it

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment a,b,c. Like

```
a=a+1;
b=b+1;
c=c+1;
```

Currently you are adding the indexes which is giving you incorrect output.

Comment: it is similar to what TZHX said.